# Encoding mailto: fields with Lektor, email cloaking with Lektor

Tags: jinja2, mailto, email-spam, lektor

I want to "encode" mailto: fields on my web-page using Javascript to avoid SPAM. (This is also known as Email cloaking.)

I saw some implementation of this Idea [here](https://jumk.de/nospam/stopspam.html).

Now I'd like to add this *mail address obfuscation* functionality to the lektor admin interface.

Where (lektor-framework-wise) and how (plugin, addon, template, flowblock, type) would be the simplest way to achieve this?

I imagine an available (flow-)block in the admin interface with fields where I could enter:

- the **mail address as a string** (which will be encoded) and
- an additional **replacement string** (which would be rendered on the webpage). The string shall be decoded "on click" only - on mouseover I see `(javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto('nbjmup;kvfshfoAkvnl/ef'));`

Building the page with lektor should yield no plaintext e-mail addresses. And preferably enable the user to add it to a paragraph "inline".

I am also open to recommendations regarding better ways to avoid spam while enabling someone to contact you via e-mail.

Comment: Related in General: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193312/encrypt-mailto-email-addresses-with-inline-javascript

Conceptual close relative (except it is about interpreting markdown instead of a separate block type): https://github.com/yargies/lektor-nofollow

Comment: General mailto: obfuscation ideas: https://csarven.ca/hiding-email-addresses